# upload file with flask WTForm

Tags: flask, file-upload, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to upload the photo using WTForms:

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    photo = FileField('')
```

part of the function on validate form

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    image = form.photo.data
        print(image)
        if image:
        image.save(os.path.join(app.instance_path, img_folder, filename))
```

html

```
 <span style="font-size:12px">Загрузить фото:</span>
    {{ form.photo }}
```

it says:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'

the line print(image) simply gives me the filename of uploaded file

whatta hay is the problem?

Comment: Was the form submitted with the enctype "multipart/form-data"? [Example](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/form/?highlight=File%20upload#file-uploads)

Comment: yes, I already add it to the form
"<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('web_form') }}" style="font-weight: bold;" enctype="multipart/form-data">"
Now it says:
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'data'